# need to return json data from spring mvc controller

Tags: ajax, json, spring, jakarta-ee

I am trying to return a Map from spring mvc controller making an ajax call but i am not getting correct resposne.

I have used mvc annotation tag in my config file and also included the jackson jar file in my library.

The requirement for me is to return Map to success of my Ajax call so i can modify a table row in html.

Code for the controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pricingrecall.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<Integer,String>  pricingUpdate(@RequestParam(value = "opp_Code", required = false) String opp_Code,
            @RequestParam(value = "ref_id", required = false) String ref_id,
            ModelMap model,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, Exception{

            String User="fe0777";
        List<CrossListViewBean>updatedRow = new ArrayList<CrossListViewBean>();
        //String message="";
        logger.info(methodLocation+"|"+"Calling pricing recall ....");
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        updatedRow=crossCampService.getupdatedrowListview(opp_Code, ref_id, user);
        Map<Integer,String> lbean= new HashMap<Integer,String>(); 
        lbean=crossCampService.getUpdatedDataPosition(updatedRow.get(0));
        return lbean;

    }
```

Call from Ajax:

```
                                    jQuery.ajax( {                                         
                                    url : '/Web/pricingrecall.do',
                type: "POST",
                cache : false,
                timeout : 60000,
                data : {
                    opp_Code :CampId ,
                    ref_id : index
                },
                success : function(result, textStatus, request) {
                    if(result)
                    {   
                        alert(result);
                        //jQuery(".note"+index).html(data);

                    }else
                    {
                        alert("The user session has timed out. Please log back in to the service.");
                        window.location.replace("logout.do");
                    }
                },
                error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("The system has encountered an unexpected error or is currently unavailable. Please contact the support number above if you have any questions.");
                }
            });
```

Here in the ajax sucess i am always getting error ,it gets diverted tot he error string.
How can i get the Json from MAp in the ajax sucess

Please help

Comment: Show some code. In other words http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: have updated my question : requirement is i need the json resposne from the controller : it should be { 1: Denver,2:texas} etc

Comment: did you declare a json object mapper?

Comment: where do i need to declare a json object mapper

Answer (score 0):

I'm using flexjson to get the json output correct. I'm attaching a sample code of mine, using flexjson. You can use this as a reference and restructure your controller method to output the correcct json. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582752/how-to-serialize-mapstring-listobject-with-flexjson) will help you in how to serialize a map.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> findUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
     User user = userService.find(id);

     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

     return new ResponseEntity<String>(user.toJson(), headers, HttpStatus.OK); 
}

@Entity
public class AppUser {
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    //Getter Setter goes here

    public String AppUser.toJson() {
       return new JSONSerializer().exclude("*.class").serialize(this);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used jackson-databind and with @ResponseBody annotation on controller methods, it automatically converted returned data to json successfully. If you use maven, add these dependencies to your pom.xml (jackson.version is 2.4.0 for me).

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Otherwise, you can add the jar files to your classpath.