# How to serialize Map with values being Lists to JSON?

Tags: java, flexjson

I need to serialize this particular object with flexJSON 2.0:

```
public class DiagramNodeDataSerializableRepresentation {

    private List<Node> nodes;
    private Map<Node, List<NodeOutput>> connections;

    public DiagramNodeDataSerializableRepresentation() {

    }

    public List<Node> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    public void setNodes(List<Node> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    public Map<Node, List<NodeOutput>> getConnections() {
        return connections;
    }

    public void setConnections(Map<Node, List<NodeOutput>> connections) {
        this.connections = connections;
    }

}
```

Where Node & NodeOutput are just POJOs with only some string fields.
I'm got stuck with Map >.
I've tried many different approaches without success.
Could you help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the deepSerialize method instead of the usual serialize worked for me:

```
    DiagramNodeDataSerializableRepresentation p = createTestData();
    JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
    String retval = serializer.deepSerialize( p );
```

This answer to a similar question will tell you all you need to know: [How to serialize Map<String, List<Object>> with FlexJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582752/how-to-serialize-mapstring-listobject-with-flexjson?rq=1)